# Python : Can I do front end of django project using HTML / CSS?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

Hi I am totally new to web development frameworks .I am currently  learning python and django  from  the  [Django project tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/)..

My (rather dumb) question is when I am done with the small "poll" website will I be able to modify the front end of this project using HTML/CSS ?

Also, should I use tools like Dreamweaver to do that ? or are there other ways ?

Comment: [pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is a fantastic ide, they have a free trial. (btw I don't work there).

Comment: Check out the django-pinax-bootstrap app, installable with "pip". It's a Twitter Bootstrap 2.0 front end packaged as a Django template. That way you have something working quickly and can mod it easily from there.

Twitter Bootstrap:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

pinax-theme-bootstrap:
https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you will be able. That is the point of the web frameworks to let you build the whole application including frontend.

You'll get it all once you finish the tutorial. You'll see that Django has very nice templating language that allows you to build a html page according to data you get from your application.

```
<h1>{{ section.title }}</h1>
```

This result in normal HTML page in the end. And of course you can write any kind of CSS for those pages to get whatever look for your page you like.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you'll need to edit the templates in the location specified by TEMPLATE_DIRS. The templates are just html mixed with some python code to fill the content.